# Como não afetar próximos elementos da mesma tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um menu horizontal com vários elementos `<li>`. Mas ao passar o *mouse* sobre o último item, ou seja sobre o último elemento `<li>` - "Serviços", abre uma outra lista de itens que também contém elementos com a tag `li`.

O problema é que nesta segunda lista de itens não quero que sejam aplicados os estilos da lista anterior (primeira lista). Como posso contornar isto?

Segue o HTML:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
.breadcrumb {
    padding: 0px;
    background: #D4D4D4;
    list-style: none; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.breadcrumb>li+li:before {
    padding: 0;
}
.breadcrumb li { 
    float: left; 
}
.breadcrumb li.active a {
    background: brown;                   
    background: #ffc107 ; 
}
.breadcrumb li.completed a {
    background: brown;                   
    background: hsla(153, 57%, 51%, 1); 
}
.breadcrumb li.active a:after {
    border-left: 30px solid #ffc107 ;
}
.breadcrumb li.completed a:after {
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(153, 57%, 51%, 1);
} 

.breadcrumb li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 10px 0 10px 45px;
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.breadcrumb li a:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(0, 0%, 83%, 1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2; 
} 
.breadcrumb li a:before { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;    
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-left: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1; 
} 
.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.breadcrumb li a:hover { 
    background: #ffc107  ; 
}
.breadcrumb li a:hover:after { 
    border-left-color: #ffc107   !important; 
}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Noticias</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown ">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle  Negrito" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <span class="caret"></span></a>        
                        <div class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
                            <div class="widget-box">
                                <div class="widget-title">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-carousel">
                                        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Serviço 1</a> </li>
                                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Serviço 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Serviço 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Serviço 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: crie uma classe especifica para o estilo que você quer aplicar ao invés de usar o li: Os li que você quer o efeito aplicado adicione por exemplo <class ='meuefeito'> e no css você estiliza o .meuEfeito

Comment: @Bsalvo O problema que tenho alguns efeitos de hover, before, que não funcionam quando crio a class sem o efeito cascata nos li. Não sei porque da isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o nosso amigo @Bsalvo disse, adicione classes concretas aos elementos que quer adicionar os estilos pretendido:

> ```
> .breadcrumb .bread-li { 
>     /* estilos aqui */
> }
> .breadcrumb .bread-li.active .bread-link {
>     /* estilos aqui */
> }
> ```

Ou podes utilizar direto um *[child-selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)* da seguinte maneira:

> ```
> .breadcrumb > li {
>     /* estilos aqui */
> }
> .breadcrumb > li.active > a {
>     /* estilos aqui */
> }
> ```

Com um pouco de magia de ambos os mundos, podes fazer algo como no código abaixo:

> ### Edição:
>
> Voltei a adicionar a classe `nav-tabs`, pois vejo que a intenção é de criar um mega-menu com várias opções de *tabs*.

```html
<!-- BIBLITECAS JQUERY E BOOTSTRAP -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- ESTILO NECESSITA SER IMPLEMENTADO DEPOIS DO CSS BOOTSTRAP -->
<style>
.breadcrumb {
    padding: 0px;
    background: #D4D4D4;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
    padding: 0;
}
.breadcrumb .bread-li { 
    float: left; 
}
.breadcrumb .bread-li.active > a {
    background: brown;                   
    background: #ffc107 ; 
}
.breadcrumb .bread-li.completed > a {
    background: brown;                   
    background: hsla(153, 57%, 51%, 1); 
}
.breadcrumb .bread-li.active > a:after {
    border-left: 30px solid #ffc107 ;
}
.breadcrumb .bread-li.completed > a:after {
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(153, 57%, 51%, 1);
} 

.breadcrumb .bread-li > a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 10px 0 10px 45px;
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.breadcrumb .bread-li > a:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(0, 0%, 83%, 1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2; 
} 
.breadcrumb .bread-li > a:before { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;    
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-left: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1; 
} 
.breadcrumb .bread-li:first-child > a {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.breadcrumb .bread-li > a:hover { 
    background: #ffc107  ; 
}
.breadcrumb .bread-li > a:hover:after { 
    border-left-color: #ffc107   !important; 
}
.breadcrumb > li.dropdown {
    position: static;
}
</style>

<!-- O CÓDIGO -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="bread-li"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="bread-li"><a href="#">Noticias</a></li>
                    <li class="bread-li dropdown mega-dropdown ">
                        <a href="#" class="caret-link dropdown-toggle Negrito" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>        
                        <div class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
                            <div class="widget-box">
                                <div class="widget-title">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-carousel">
                                        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Serviço 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Serviço 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Serviço 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Serviço 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Exemplo no jsFiddle usando apenas *child-selectors*: https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/0otautec/3/

No entanto nem sempre é aconselhável utilizar a segunda opção, pois quando se trata de projetos de grandes dimensões, aninhar elementos no CSS dessa maneira pode ser uma dor de cabeça.

> **NOTA:** Algumas tags como *links* "`<a>`" não se encontram devidamente encerradas, O HTML5 não se importa com isto e automaticamente faz o encerramento delas, mas há que ter isso em conta pois não é nada uma boa prática, poderá ter problemas de validação em versões do HTML anteriores e poderá afetar o seu trabalho quando estiver trabalhando na sua plataforma.

Comment: Então, mais esta alterando os elemento da tag `<li>` dentro da `<ul>` com classe `nav`.

Comment: Retiro meu comentario acima. Eu tinha testado antes da sua ultima edição e percebi agora e refiz o teste. Resposta exatamente como o pretendido. Obrigado.

Comment: Uma duvida que não tem haver com a pergunta. Sabe me dizer porque o mega-menu no chrome ao trocar de tab ele fica abrindo e fechando sozinho ao passar o mouse por cima ?

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro Ao passar o mouse por cima para mim ele não fecha, mas agora se clicar sim, ele fecha. Estou usando a Versão 59.0.3071.115 . Mas é mesmo parte da sua função ele fechar mesmo quando acontece um clique.

Comment: Estou com a mesma versão, conhece como contornar a situação de ter um clique dentro e ele não fechar. As vezes ele fecha sozinho so de eu estar trocando de tab.

Comment: Isto deve fazer o truque @WillianCoqueiro : https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/0otautec/4/ . Se for necessário também para o `hover` é só mudar a segunda linha para `$('.breadcrumb .dropdown').on({'click hover': function(event) {` ou seja, acrescentar o `hover` em frente do evento `click`.

Comment: Estranho e que nos seu exemplo so abre ao clica e aqui comigo abre ao passar o mouse. O problema está ai, mais não sei de onde está vindo este comando.

Comment: Eu mesmo tinha feito uma função JavaScript para que quando passasse o mouse por cima abrisse, como fiz a uns dias atrás esqueci dela. kkkk Estão junto com a sua função esta conflitando. Obrigado pela atenção. Irei Adicionar todos seus comentário aqui como algo util.